# How to add a block at the very top of every page?

Tags: static-block, blocks

I would like to know how to add a block at the very top of every page in my website.

It would be just a 'bar' with the purpose of displaying important information periodically, like - for example - when I am on holiday and unable to process orders.  Or perhaps when there is a promotion running.

It's position would be above the site's header section - exactly where the cookie restriction banner gets placed by default.

Ideally I'd like it to be a block so that it's easily enabled/disabled and edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it easily via layout update file, `local.xml` for example.

```
<default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="cms/block" name="my_static_block">
            <action method="setBlockId"><value>my_static_block</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Now you just have to create a static block with `my_static_block` identifier, put some content in and you are done.