# How to create custom local.xml to prevent Magento upgrade from losing changes

Tags: local.xml

I'm familiar with child themes for Magento and the fallback mechanism Magento utilises, but I am not familiar with how the local.xml file works.

The other day I asked a question on here and the answer was to add to the local.xml file.  See here:
[How to add a block at the very top of every page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53212/how-to-add-a-block-at-the-very-top-of-every-page)

Now, I did that with success but since then I have upgraded my Magento version to 1.9.1 and have just realised that my changes have now gone from the local.xml file.

How do you modify the local.xml file so that it won't revert back when you upgrade Magento versions?

Does it work in the same manner as themes, where you can create a copy of the local.xml file and place it in the child directory?

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, there are two possibilities for the above issue.

- After the upgrade, did you check your static block does exist and is enabled ? Also make sure it has it's unique id as `my_static_block`.
- This may be the most possible reason for this issue. From `magento 1.9`, the default theme used by magento is `rwd` > `default`. So my guess is, you were using your own custom package > theme in your older version and so that your `local.xml` file exists in that custom theme. You need to move it to `rwd > default` theme. ie to the location `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.  Yes I have tested the static block is enabled.  The code in the local.xml is definitely not there anymore.  I will try your step 2 and let you know.  Best regards